# Batch File to Output Subfolders sorted by Date Modified and # of Files

Tags: batch-file, text, output

I am trying to write a simple batch file that will list the subfolders that begin with "@" of a particular folder in which the batch file resides, sort those files by date modified, and tell me the number of files within each subfolder. Here is my code, which works perfectly except that it always outputs the number of files as "0" which is incorrect:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%D IN ('DIR *.* /-P /O:G-DE ^| FIND "@"') DO     (
    FOR /F %%K IN ('DIR "%%D" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "File(s)" ^|^| ECHO 0') DO (
        ECHO %%D %%K>>Test1.txt
    )
)
```

When I do a test batch file just to output the number of files in the subfolders, it works (although it gives the number of files in the folder and total number of files as well, but at least I'm getting the number of files per subfolder):

```
FOR /F %%K IN ('DIR /S ^| FIND "File(s)"') DO ECHO %%K >>Test2.txt
```

I just can't seem to get it to work when I combine the two bits of code to simply give me the names of the subfolders + number of files (one line per subfolder). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Get rid of the `ECHO 0` from your initial code.

Comment: Thank you @SomethingDark for the reply! When I remove only 'ECHO 0' from the code, the batch files runs but does not create the output text files. Same thing if I remove the '^|^|' as well. Am I just missing something easy? Thanks!

Comment: Your code does actually not return folders beginning with `@` but files _and_ folders that _contain_ `@`; to get what you want use `dir /-P /A:-D /O:-DE "@*" and omit `| find "@"`...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @aschipfl! I tried your modification but it only gave a partial list of the relevant files and then it stopped working after I tried it a couple more times. My version always gives just the "@" subfolders; so that part of the code works fine. I just need it to also list the number of files per each "@" subfolder in the output text file.

Comment: Oops, I made a typo -- it should read `dir /-P /A:D /O:-DE "@*"` (I typed `/A:-D` before erroneously), sorry!

Comment: HI @aschipfl, your method and my method both output the "@" subfolders, but your method also gives some additional folder info that I don't need in the text file. Any idea on how to output the number of files for each subfolder as well? It just seems like the 2nd and 3rd lines of my code aren't working as intended.....Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd add the switch `/B` (so it's `dir /B /-P /A:D /O:-DE "@*"`), so you get a pure list of folders beginning with `@`; this can be parsed using `for /F "delims=" %%D`, then do something like `dir "%%~D" | find "File(s)"` to get the number of files for each of the `@`-folders...

Comment: For some reason `/B` was key in giving me the correct number of files per each "@" folder! I've ran into other errors, but almost have a solution, which I'll post when I finish. Thanks @aschipfl for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The command line `dir *.* /-P /O:G-DE | find "@"` you are using actually returns files *and* directories that *contain* `@`. To get only *directories* that *begin* with `@`, use the command line `dir /-P /A:D /O:-DE "@*"`. The switch `/A:D` lets `dir` return directories only; the pattern `@*` means items beginning with `@`, there is no need for `find`.

Now let us use `for /F` to walk through all items. For this, add the switch `/B` to `dir` to avoid any headers in the output and return a pure directory list:

```
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('
    dir /B /-P /A:D /O:-DE "@*"
') do (
    rem print each item:
    echo "%%~D"
)
```

So let us concentrate on the number of files contained in each of the listed directories now. Your method using `dir` and searching for the line containing the text `File(s)` by `find` works fine basically. There is no need for `echo 0` as `dir` returns the summary line also for empty directories. But you need to consider items that contain the string `File(s)` in their names. So the following code should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
> "Test1.txt" (
    for /F "delims=" %%D in ('
        dir /B /-P /A:D /O:-DE "@*"
    ') do (
        for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%K in ('
            dir /-P "%%~D" ^| find "File(s)"
        ') do (
            set "numItems=%%K"
        )
        echo "%%~D" !numItems!
    )
)
endlocal
```

The redirection to a text file is done once rather than for every loop iteration. I also removed the `2> nul` from the inner `dir` command as the enumerated directory will exist for sure (it is retrieved by the outer `dir`), so there will be no error messages.

The inner loop does not produce an output but assigns the number of files to a variable `numItems`. This loop normally iterates once, but if a file contains `File(s)` in its name, it iterates twice -- the first time for the file and the second time for the summary line. Since the variable `numItems` is overwritten, it always contains the last value which is the expected number (as the summary line is at the end).
This method requires to produce the output by an `echo` *after* the inner loop. This requires delayed environment variable expansion, which is enabled by the `setlocal` command and actually used by the syntax `!numItems!` rather than `%numItems%`. Type `set /?` for more information on this.

Note that the search string `File(s)` need to be adapted accordingly on non-English systems.

Comment: See my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34117733/2): I just added the `@echo off` line to the script to avoid command echoes to also be written to `Text1.txt`...